# Print table data

Tags: css, printing, css-tables

I have a table with scrollbar if I print the table I am getting half of the table.. I want to print whole table data.

Following is my CSS:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' media="all" type='text/css' href='<?=$this->baseUrl('/scripts/jquery/plugins/weekcalendar/demo.css')?>' />  

.wc-scrollable-grid {
     overflow: auto;
     overflow-x: hidden !important;
     overflow-y: auto !important; 
     position: relative;
     background-color: #fff;
     width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Check in developer tools, if your table got all the records. Provide some more context.

Comment: yes, have the all the records..i am trying to upload the image but i need min 10 points in stackoverflow.but let me explain clearly.. i have a table with scrollbar..i have 30 records totally but when i print i am getting 1 to 10 only.

Answer (score 0):

The crucial thing here is how you restrict the height of the table or its container. This part of the code is not disclosed in the question, but assuming a simple declaration like

```
  .wc-scrollable-grid {
    height: 250px;
  }
```

...the solution is simply to make this restricted to screen media, e.g.

```
  @media screen {
    .wc-scrollable-grid {
       height: 250px;
    }
  }
```

A more structured way is to divide your stylesheet into three parts: rules that should apply on any media; rules that should apply on screen only; and rules that should apply in print only. And you would then use three `link` elements, each with a different `media` attribute.